# Prevent default as part of form validation JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to validate a form which is here.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="bandForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br  />
                    <label for="bandName" class="control-label">Band Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bandName" id="bandName"><br  /><br  />
                    <label for="genre">Genre</label>
                    <select name="genre" id="genre">
                              <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
                              <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
                              <option value="Folk">Folk</option>
                              <option value="Metal">Heavy Metal</option>
                            </select><br  /><br  />
                    <label for="video">Enter the URL for one of your youTube videos</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="video" id="video"><br  />
                    <label for="bio">Biography</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" columns="4" class="form-control" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
                    </fieldset><br  />

                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

What I'm trying to do is to make so that if any of the fields are blank then the form doesn't send and the error messages display. Of course if everything is filled in then I want the form to submit. Here is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bandForm").submit(function(e){

     var errorMessage="";

     if($('#bandName').val() == ''){
        errorMessage="<br />Please enter a band name";
     }

     if($('#video').val() == ''){
        errorMessage=errorMessage+"<br />Please enter the URL of one of your band's YouTube videos";
     }

     if($('#bio').val() == ''){
        errorMessage=errorMessage+"<br />Please enter a band biography";
     }
     if (!errorMessage=="") {

      $("#error").html(errorMessage);
      e.preventDefault();  

      }

    });
  });
```

The form seems to submit regardless of what I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you try to do `return false` if there was any error?

Comment: I've not used return false before, could you give an example of how you think I should use it in this scenario?

Comment: Just `e.preventDefault(); return false;` in your code